# What time frame might I expect to correct arm rotation?

Tags: therapy

My arms are rotated so that the back of my hands face directly forward.  This is presumably from years and years of sitting at a computer.  I am attempting to correct it by doing only pull exercises: bent-over rows and deadlifts, as well as stretches for pec minor and the various back and shoulder muscles.  Additionally, I am doing wall slides.

My question is, assuming this routine will correct the muscle imbalances that have led to my arm rotation, what approximate time frame might I expect the correction to occur by?  E.g. on the order of weeks?  Months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions are tough because they're essentially "how long is a piece of string" type guesses.

You're going to start seeing improvement slowly but surely, and eventually you'll get decreasing gains where changing a few degrees will take a much longer amount of time.

Good on you for doing bent over rows and deadlifts (really terrific exercises), but rather than going at it from a physical therapy prospective I'd really recommend a proper and balanced strength training routine. Make sure you're doing some standing overhead press work, dips, and flat or incline bench pressing as well. Even pushups would be better than nothing in that department.

You got into this predicament by being out of balance in the first place, so trying to out-smart your body's preferred state of affairs might seem like a great idea but it's not going to work well in the long run.

Comment: I understand that it's difficult to give an accurate timeframe, I was just looking for an order of magnitude type estimate.  A month, several months...

Comment: From a medical background we can never give anyone a definitive time frame. This is because everyone is different. I know it sounds like a cop out; but, it really is true. It depends on why your arms are rotated in. In your post assume (and I agree sounds the most logical) it is from years of being hunched at a keyboard. I think @EricKaufman has your best answer. Put in the work from a well rounded perspective and if you stop seeing results or develop pains seek medical advice.